# A horror from the past

Tags: riddle, knowledge

When the word horror is about to fall,

This person sits in a throne above all.

---

All life ends at one point,

for bringing them back makes them another worlds joint.

---

While the death are having a blast,

one struggles with memories of the past.

---

It's not worth to disturb nature,

whether it be a ritual or mythical creature.

---

**What is the title of this book/movie?**

EDIT since no one found an answer yet, here is a hint:

> It was first a book, then a movie and then a remake of the movie.

Comment: I'm like 60% sure the first word is BOOKING, but I don't know the rest. Anybody else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book and movie are:

> Pet Sematary

When the word horror is about to fall,
This person sits in a throne above all.

> Stephen King, of course

All life ends at one point,
for bringing them back makes them another worlds joint.

> Spoiler Alert - the story is about unholy resurrections

While the death are having a blast,
one struggles with memories of the past.

> The protagonist is remorseful about his lost patient and lost daughter

It's not worth to disturb nature,
whether it be a ritual or mythical creature.

> The resurrections are performed by a spirit named Wendigo

From the Hint:

> The book was published in 1983. The first movie was released in 1989. The most-recent remake was released in 2019.

Comment: Ding Ding you are correct on every single point good job!